How to improve build and compile times in Policy Center (one hour+ to build currently)?
The long build times are currently a productivity killer.
Are there any configuration / vm properties that can be added to improve build and compile times for developers? Can the product model validation be disabled? Can the database upgrade be disabled?
Our company has a huge product model that is causing build times for Policy Center to take over an hour. Using self-managed version 10.
Thanks in advance for any help.

It might be hard for anyone to provide a good answer on this question. A lot of carriers see this issue and there are multiple things to tinker with. If you can answer these questions then myself and others might be able to provide helpful suggestions. How many products defined in your product model? Is the hour long build time in the local studio environment or also in the CICD (Jenkins or other build tool) process? The database upgrade question seems irrelevant when talking about build times, but perhaps you are also talking about the time it takes for a local jetty server to start?

Thanks for the response. We currently have 24 product lines defined (and growing) encompassing thousands of coverages.
The long build times also occur when building through CICD - though it affects developer productivity the most when trying to build locally.
Is there any tinkering we can do to limit the amount of products that are loaded on startup?

At the end of the Build process messages reporting the time spent in different phases of the build are reported.  Not that it will help much, but can you post those times for a typical studio build?  Normally the bulk of the time is spent in the Gosu Compile phase.  The only way to reduce that time is to reduce the number of classes to act on.  If there is any content of significant size that you could convert to Java and jar up, that is the only mechanism I'm aware of to reduce the size of your Gosu footprint.  Additionally, are you on fast local storage?

I'm afraid there is no one-size-fits-all solution to this problem. It will take some experimentation and playing around with certain properties and settings. I believe that you are referring to the overall compilation process of PolicyCenter along with the time taken for the Jetty server startup. Here are some things you can try:
1. Tweaking gradle build properties
As already pointed out, you can tweak multiple properties in gradle.properties after determining which section of the compile process takes the most time. Here are some properties that I have fiddled around with in the past and seen positive results:

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms2g -Xmx8g


These JVM arguments set the minimum (-Xms) and maximum (-Xmx) heap
sizes for the Gradle daemon. Allocating sufficient memory can improve
performance, as it allows more data to be cached in memory. However,
if too much memory is allocated, it may negatively impact other
applications running on the system.

So to start with I would double both the min and max heap and observe if that makes a difference. Please note that the gradle demon can easily run out of sufficient heap which makes the compile process a lot slower.

org.gradle.parallel=true


Enabling parallel execution allows Gradle to use multiple threads to
execute tasks concurrently. This can significantly improve build
times, especially for projects with independent tasks that can be
executed in parallel.

This is true by default and I would just double-check that parallel execution didn't get disabled by accident in your case.

org.gradle.workers.max=5


This property sets the maximum number of worker threads that can be
used by Gradle for parallel execution. A lower value may limit the
potential speed gains from parallel execution, while a higher value
may increase the risk of resource contention and out-of-memory errors.

2 is the default value and it is possible to see positive results by increasing the number of threads to 4 or 5, especially with PolicyCenter.

org.gradle.daemon=true


Disabling the Gradle daemon means a new JVM process is started for
each build, which can increase build startup time. Enabling the daemon
(org.gradle.daemon=true) typically speeds up build times by reusing
the same JVM process for multiple builds, allowing the JVM to warm up
and cache data.

This is disabled by default but I have seen minor improvements by setting this property to true.
You can also tweak Java or Gosu compile heap sizes but they're usually sufficient and less likely to cause an issue. In case the build messages report an unusually high compile time for Gosu, Product Model, or Java, you can give them more heap to see if it makes a difference.
2. Using better hardware
It took a while for me to realize that PolicyCenter along with SBTs and all the ISO greatness is a monstrous monolith that requires more than average hardware or VMs to build and run. So here is a checklist I would follow:

Make sure your disk is SSD (or NvMe) based rather than being an HDD. Newest gen SSDs have a significant IOPS which can make all the difference in the world when building huge monoliths.

Use a newer-gen processor with a better clock speed and at least 8 cores. My i9 10th gen has been able to grind most SBT builds within minutes. So I would recommend at least an i7 or an enterprise-level equivalent from either Intel or AMD. I have observed that Apple's M2 / M2 pro are great performers as well.

Have at least 24G of RAM. I have seen cases when I had to use 32 or 48G but that was because I was running multiple apps at the same time. 32 is a must if you want to bump up gradle, build and JVM heaps to a higher number.


3. Avoid pre-loading of classes
Clear your preload.txt file to prevent pre-loading of a bunch of classes at server startup. If you are using SBT along with the EDGE package, it is known to pre-load hundreds of classes thereby adding to the server startup time. Note that this will add a cost of lazy loading the class at runtime but it may not even be required on a dev's local. E.g. A dev working on configuration may never invoke the Edge API classes so there is no point in pre-loading them.
4. Upgrade to a newer and more stable on-prem version of PolicyCenter
Early versions of PC like 10.0.2 were kind of experimental and had multiple bugs that caused PC to take longer than anticipated. I would recommend upgrading to at least 10.2.X to stay up to date with Guidewire's latest patches.
Keep experimenting with the above until you find the sweet spot and the right combination of settings and hardware.

All these are good and I would re-emphasize point #4. Early versions of InsuranceSuite apps in version 10 had some significant issues. Upgrade to the latest version of 10 ASAP.

Inside your PolicyCenter dir you can find gradle.properties. You can play around with the value in that file. You can also change -Xms and -Xmx value in your studio. If that does not help. Set SchedulerEnabled=false inside config.xml that has helped me.

I have found that compiling and starting the local jetty server does take less time when doing these from the cmd prompt. So running gwb compile and gwb runServer with all the appropriate options is usually a little faster than running from studio. As Kishor said, you can adjust the memory settings to possibly improve performance of the compile command, but I have had mixed results with this. If you adjust the memory settings I would set the -Xms and the -Xmx to the same value so that the compile process does not have to incrementally allocate more memory. For the compile job in PC default settings are 2GB min and 16GB max.
Documentation link (login required): https://docs.guidewire.com/self-managed/pc/1023/admin/admin/topics/r_tune-memory-settings.html
From gradle.properties:
custDistGosuCompileMinHeapSize=2g
custDistGosuCompileMaxHeapSize=16g

Running the commands separately:
gwb compile
gwb runServer -x compile

The second command starts the server without the dependency on the compile task. If you needed to start the server but still potentially debug using studio:
gwb runServer -x compile --debug-socket

And of course you could also add the -Denv=someenvname option if you needed to pass an environment variable.
As Marty said in a comment, the compile time is mostly determined by the number of Gosu classes to churn through so I wouldn't expect any of the suggestions in this answer to cut down the build time significantly. But these suggestions are worth a try and your mileage may vary.
